# Name suggestions for OpenSource organisation and MVC CMS Project

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, open-source, naming

Hey guys, a couple of us are looking for a collaborative name to work under when developing OpenSource products. The first of which will be an MVC CMS which is designed to be as usable as possible (no admin system all editing done inline).

So can you help us name the two:

- OpenSource Organisation - mainly dealing with .net and mvc solutions
- MVC CMS - which is highly usable and intuiative

Thanks our efforts have failed us so far. We may even give a prize to the winner.

Update: We settled on OpenQuarters for our organisation and WebQuarters for our CMS more information at: http://www.openquarters.org

Comment: What next? Please suggest a name for my puppy?

Comment: We are hoping that its members of this site that will end up using the system and contributing to the project, we are confident that it will be well approved of due to its modern architecture and web 2.0 style approach

Comment: Did you actually started the project? I'm looking for a open source .net project to participate in and I'm interested in yours.

Comment: Yes check out our website on http://www.openquarters.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSource Organisation: PeopleFlow. Because it's always about people, workflows and [flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) ("usable and intuiative")

MVC CMS: PeopleFlow Web Headquarters (HQ): Web Headquarters (HQ) because CMS it too technical and because you need a concept that covers all of the functionality and business aspects of a CMS. You need the PeopleFlow because Web HQ is too generic and because it's better branding.

Comment: We have actually gone with OpenQuarters.org based upon your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

ModelViewContent - no fuss, just editing inline.

Answer (score 0):

- openMVC
- crudMVC

Answer (score 0):

freeMVC
OpenNet